# JavaFX: Set Background Color in TextFlow

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I have a text flow widget in my JavaFx application for which I need to change the background color.

The layout is constructed using FXML, and the background color for the text flow needs to be set using external css file.

I'm able to set the background color for both textArea and textField, but unable to do so for textFlow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply set the `-fx-background-color` property the same way you'd do it for other `Region`s e.g.:

```css
TextFlow {
    -fx-background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: It worked. I had been using ".text-flow" as the css selector. It started working once I used "TextFlow" as the selector.

Comment: @spam Only `Control` subclasses have CSS classes set by default. Using `.text-flow` would work if you explicitly set the style class (`styleClass="text-flow"` in FXML).